# Lossless rendering of sprites in case of zoom out in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

So I'm very new to unity and I am facing issues while importing a sprite which is a deck of playing cards. The problem here is that when I start zooming out the camera the sprites start looking weird(pixelated).
I want them to be clear when I zoom out my game camera.

The below is the layout which I want. I made use of a 3d object(tile) on which I am currently adding a sprite.[image: sprite when zoomed Out]

As you can see above is a sprite when zoomed out and you cannot make out the number which is written on the cards.

The same sprite when zoomed in the cards appear to be normal as shown below.

[image: sprite when zoomed in]

Please do suggest me any measure or a way for me to achieve such layout while the cards being see-able by the users.
PS. I can reduce the gap between the cards and keep them next to each other as well.